# Arithmetic overflow when upgrading from .Net 4 to .Net 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net

When upgrading a project from .Net 4 to .Net 4.6.1 (and .Net 4.7.2)I get an arithmetic overflow on the line below. Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening?

```
bitmap = new Bitmap(viewArea.Width, viewArea.Height, stride, source.Bitmap.PixelFormat, 
                (IntPtr)(((int)byteArray.bitPtr)+startOffset));
```

Comment: That `(int)` cast has to go, use byteArray.bitPtr + 4*startOffset

Comment: Wow, that was quick! And it worked. Thanks very much